# important tailwind class in .scss

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I would like to make important a tailwind class in scss file.

I have done it like this but it returns error and seems does not support:

```
.test-scss{
  @apply flex justify-center md:!justify-end;
}
```

can anyone tell me what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

## Preface:

The most important thing to understand about using Tailwind with a preprocessor like Sass is that preprocessors run separately, before Tailwind. This means that you can’t feed the output from the Tailwind into a Sass, because the Tailwind isn’t actually evaluated until your Sass has been compiled to CSS and fed into PostCSS.

When using Tailwind with Sass, using `!important` with `@apply` requires you to use interpolation to compile properly. Otherwise Sass will complain about using `!important`.

## Solution:

*Try using interpolation as a workaround*

```
.test-scss {
  @apply flex justify-center md:justify-end #{!important};
}
```

Additionally, if we want to make one part of the scss important for example "md:justify-end". we can try the following.

```
.test-scss {
  @apply flex justify-center;

  @screen md {
    @apply justify-end #{!important};
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors

Comment: I would like to make important only one class (justify-end).
your code still returns error because of "!" before "justify-end"

Comment: it makes the code messy. you need add a line for add a class and then make it important. I am looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
.test-scss{
    @apply flex justify-center;
    @apply md:justify-end !important
}
```

Important that you put it on two lines to not have all the properties get the !important